# How can I pass a ModelAndView as parameter to a ModelAndView or a workaround?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
ModelAndView content= new ModelAndView("myPage", "message", message);

return new ModelAndView("template", "content", content);
```

I am trying to create the page content and pass it as parameter to the template.jsp

myPage.jsp has its own logic and needs to do its own calculations. So it needs to be rendered before being passed.

Is there a workaround to this or a better design choice of implement a template style structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean with "has its own logic and needs to do its own calculations"?

Comment: For example inside the myPage.jsp I  have if statements, jsp code and other variables that are calculated and passed on the modelandview prior to passing to the template. Template could include its own logic as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to get an instance of `ModelMap` injected to your controller method by the spring.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home(ModelMap model){
   model.put("content", "content");
   return new ModelAndView("template", model);
}
```

Alternatively you can just return String. Spring will automatically take the ModelMap instance that you have injected to the controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(ModelMap model){
   model.put("key","value")
   return "template";
}
```

Comment: I am having difficulty to understand what you mean by this code. Where does myPage.jsp being passed into the template?

Comment: that will depend up on your code. are you following some tutorial? if so, please provide the link, else please post your code..

Comment: I did follow this tutorial, http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: The thing is that this tutorial just created a basic interface for the application. What I am trying to do now is display myPage.jsp inside template.jsp

Comment: if you return tempate from the controller, that `/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp` file will be returned. If you want to display one jsp inside other, you should use `<jsp:include>` or `<c:import>` commands

Comment: I understand this @redflar3, but the problem is this other .jsp lets say myPage.jsp contains its own logic and own variables (${message} for example and other if statements). How do I render it before I pass it

Comment: the rendering will happen after the include. so whatever variables you want to evaluate, you can include that in ModelMap.. in other words, what ever variables you add in ModelMap object will be evaluated in the jsp irrespective of `include level` and you dont have to render the inner jsp separately..

Comment: how implement with thymeleaf? modify the answer pls